# How to make Android ListView clickable using Hashmap?

Tags: android, android-listview, hashmap

First of all, i am sorry because there is similar question that already been asked before. I've tried but it does not worked in my program. Hence, I need some help from you to help me to finish my program. Thank you.

**Problem** : my list cannot be click to go to next activity.

ListPending.java

```
  public void getTable(String r) {
    final ListView lv;
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lsApproval);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> feedList= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    try {

        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(r);

        JSONObject jInit = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
        String valid = jInit.getString("valid");
        String none="NO";
        String empty="EMPTY";
        TextView tv;
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvNone);

        if (valid.equals(none))
        {
            TextView tv1,tv2,tv3;

            tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSname);
            tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDest);
            tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDate);

            tv.setText("\n\n\n\n\n\n" + "You do not have applicant under your approval" + "\n\n\n\n" );
            tv1.setText("");
            tv2.setText("");
            tv3.setText("");

        }
        else if (valid.equals(empty))
        {
            TextView tv1,tv2,tv3;

            tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSname);
            tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDest);
            tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDate);

            tv.setText("\n\n\n\n\n\n" + "No Pending List" + "\n\n\n\n" );
            tv1.setText("");
            tv2.setText("");
            tv3.setText("");

        }
        else
        {
            String j=String.valueOf(jArray.length());
            tv.setText("Have " +j+" applications need your approval");

            for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){

                JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String date = json.getString("dtfrom");
                StringTokenizer tk = new StringTokenizer(date);
                String dat = tk.nextToken();  // <---  yyyy-mm-dd

                String staff = json.getString("staffname");
                String dest = json.getString("destination");

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("image", String.valueOf(R.mipmap.view));
                map.put("staff", staff);
                map.put("dest", dest);
                map.put("date", dat);
                feedList.add(map);


                SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, feedList, R.layout.list_pending,
                        new String[]{"staff", "dest","date","image"},
                        new int[]{R.id.tvStaff, R.id.tvDest, R.id.tvDate, R.id.ibView});
                lv.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);


                // React to user clicks on item
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentAdapter, View view, int position,
                                            long id) {


                        Toast.makeText(ListPending.this, "try" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

            }
        }
```

it successfully show the data from database but not clickable.

[image]

Comment: Are you using custom `SimpleAdapter` or default?

Comment: i am using SimpleAdapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of problem occur when another object on the list is either focusable or clickable. The solution is to:

1. Inspect your layout xml file and make sure that none of the views you are having on your list has its `android:clickable` set to true.
2. Avoid to use any clickable view like a button on your list, as this will make your list not clickable.

Answer (score 2):

First of all find the **views** which are getting **focus** and not allow **list** to be **focused** and **touch** in all other **views** put

- `focusable=false` and `focusintouchMode=false` in **xml**

and if it is still not allowing your `listview` to be clicked then can share your problem again.

Comment: still doesnot worked.. <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lsPending"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:focusable="false" />

Comment: focusable false should use with other views in your custom layout for listview not in listview item

Answer (score 1):

Seem your view is not taking focus in listview.It's the issue of view when you click the list row, it is always the capture other view event. apply below property to your main layout in row file (list_pending.xml) and let me know whether its works or not?

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

or programmatically

```
 listView.setDescendantFocusability(ListView.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
```